# Toggle Class when scrolling over specific section.

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, toggleclass

I'm sure this question has probably been asked and answered before, but I couldn't find it, so I'm probably not searching the correct terms. I have a fixed navigation which, when clicked, scrolls the page up or down to specific sections of the page using a data-scrollto element and class. I would like to toggle an "active" class on the specific nav elements when it has reached their specific section. I could toggle a class based on the user's click, but if the user is scrolling up and down the page, I want the class to toggle when they roll over the section. Ideally, exactly when the top of the section meets the bottom of the fixed menu.

I have mocked up a codepen to try and clarify http://codepen.io/jphogan/pen/aOMjzE

I am using the following code to set the height of the container and trigger the scrolling on click to the specific section. I am using jQuery and jQuery UI.

```
var fixedHeight = $(".navWrapper").outerHeight(true);
$(".navWrapper").css("height", fixedHeight + "px");
var innerMenuHeight = $(".navWrapperInner").outerHeight(true);

var anchors = $(".sectionAnchor");
var disableChange = false;
var menuHeight;

$( ".pageScroller" ).on("click", function( ) {
    disableChange=true;
    $("a.pageScroller").removeClass("active"); // remove class from all nav links
    $(this).addClass("active"); // add to active link
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($("." + $(this).data("scrollto")).offset().top)-innerMenuHeight-17},1000,"easeInOutSine"); // scroll to section 
    window.setTimeout(function(){disableChange=false;},480);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: It seems you want to do something very similar to what [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) does. If you use the option `autoScrolling:false` as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html), you have what you want to achieve. (plus tens of more features)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var document = $(document);
var sections = [...];

// when user scrolls
document.scroll(function () {
    var
        sy = document.scrollTop() // get scroll y
    ,   h  = $(window).height()
    ;

    var bottom = null;
    $(sections).each(function (section) {
        var sectionY = getSectionAbsoluteY(section); // absolute Y position of section
        if (sectionY < sy + h) // check if bottom-most visible
            bottom = section;
    });

    $(sections).each(...); // unhighlight
    if (bottom)
        $(bottom) ... // highlight
});
```